# Scraping multiples pages in BeautifulSoup and iterating process in python

Tags: python, arrays, beautifulsoup

Hello and thank you for your help. I'm new in python and programming. I'm crawling a webpage in python with beautifulsoup, I have all the interested links in a csv document. The problem I'm having is that I can't iterate over all the links, then I want to fill the arrays and finally to construct a Data frame. My code is the following.

```
precio = []
direccion = []
titulo = []


for url in urls.values:
    url_ = url[0]
    response = get(url_)
    page = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    
    for precios in page.find("span", attrs={"class" : "ad-price"}).stripped_strings :
        precio.append(precios)

    for tit in page.find("div", attrs={"class" : "title"}).stripped_string :
        titulo.append(tit)
        
    for ubic in page.find("div", attrs = {"class" : "location-name"}) :
        direccion.append(ubic)
```

The problem I have is that for the request "precios", that is the first "for", I get correctly the values just when I ommit the other requests ("tit" and "ubic"), but when I add the tags and the code for "tit" and "ubic", a message appears me that says "'NoneType' object is not iterable", even I tried to crawl first the request for "ubic" and for "tit", but I just get the request "precios" correctly. Adding, the same thing happens with the code ".stripped_strings", that I just get the value for the request for "precios" and it doesn't function for the other requests neither with ".get_text()" in anyone. I don't know what exactly is happening. I hope I was clear. Thank you¡

Comment: Is the page loaded dynamically? If so, `requests` won't support it. Does the correct tags appear when doing `print(soup.prettify())`? What's the URL?

Comment: It is not dynamically, this is a little example of the html code when I print print(soup.prettify()). An example of just an only one url is: [link](https://www.vivanuncios.com.mx/a-departamentos-en-venta/militar-marte/residencial-la-viga/1003669782300911273880409).  Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

For this webpage, using requests library can only get the price and title details. The location data is loaded dynamically and therefore is not present in the request response. There was a problem with the way you were trying to get the title value. Below is the code to get the price and title details.

Code snippet:-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

precio = []
direccion = []
titulo = []


url='https://www.vivanuncios.com.mx/a-departamentos-en-venta/militar-marte/residencial-la-viga/1003669782300911273880409'
response = requests.get(url)
page = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

price=page.find("span", attrs={"class" : "ad-price"})
precio.append(price.text.strip())

heading_block=page.find('h1',class_='item-title')
title=heading_block.find("div", attrs={"class" : "title"})
titulo.append(title.text)

print(precio)
print(titulo)
```